What is the philosophical answer to: Why do Humans Harm the Harmless?
I am currently undergoing a philosophy project at school where we were able to choose any question to answer in the format of an essay. I have chosen this question but the amount of information I have found to answer it has been limited. If anyone could provide some insight to it, it would be greatly appreciated!

By 'harmless' are you referring only to other humans? Do you have a direction you would like to go with this, such as cultural causes, evolutionary ones, financial, etc? Are you looking for actionable information, so that it could be remedied? If you edit with more details, your question will get attention again. Good luck!
